# How to use a word as a key in hash

Tags: c

Suppose, I want to create a hash table where key is a word(combination of characters). How can I achieve this in C? Is there any inbuilt feature available to us?

Answer (score 1):

C does not provide hash tables data structures.

You can program your own or use GLib library which includes a lot of data structures including  hash tables.

http://developer.gnome.org/glib

Comment: could you please suggest me some algorithm or logic or any reference to do the same. Thank in advance

Comment: @user3686233, ouah has provided the answer.  If you feel this is too complex for you, or require more help, then you need to open a new question.  Hashing strings is a well-known algorithm.  If you're struggling with this, you might want to go back to basics before tackling this.

Comment: look up polynomial string hashes

Comment: @user3686233 I suggest The Algorithm Design Manual, 2nd Edition, by Steven Skiena http://www.algorist.com/

Answer (score 0):

Anytime i've ever needed a simple, fast hashing algorithm in C, i've looked up hash algorithms by Bob Jenkins.

Try looking here:

http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/index.html